# WaitCommEvent with Listener in C++ Winforms application

Tags: winforms, serial-port, c++-cli, listener

I'm trying to write winforms that reads data from Arduino board. CLR application does not permit threads, so I have to solve this problem with a listener. How can I trigger Listener when a data is available at the port, by using WaitCommEvent

My code is like example2 on this [site](http://members.ee.net/brey/Serial.pdf)

Comment: It doesn't permit std::thread, there is no problem at all using System::Threading::Thread or CreateThread().  Don't call WaitCommEvent yourself, let the SerialPort class do it for you.  That's how it raises its DataReceived event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DataReceived of your COM Port. User ReadLine method in your com port, example :

```
private:
    System::Void comPort1_DataReceived(System::Object ^sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs ^e)
    {
        System^ data = comPort1->ReadLine();
        this->Invoke(gcnew EventHandler(processData));
    }

    System::Void processData(System::Object ^sender, System::EventArgs ^e)
    {
        // data receive
    }
```

Using .Net, read this tutorial : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/eclipsed4utoo/communicating-with-serial-port-in-C-Sharp/.

Comment: So, you said give up using WaitCommEvent, aren't you?

Comment: Not have to, I proposed a solution fully .NET. But you can make  C++/CLI wrapper to interact Win32 API with Windows Forms app.